# res.send(body.data) is undefined

Tags: node.js, request

im trying to get another api using node request, but when i try to display body.data its return undefined

```js
router.get('/',  (req, res,next) => {

    request('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/promos',  (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) { 
            res.send('An erorr occured')
            console.log(error)
        }
        else {
            res.send(body.data)
        }
    });
});
```

anyone know whats wrong

Comment: Do `console.log(body)`, not `console.log(body.data)`.

Comment: but i need the data only, not all result from the body

Comment: Well, `request()` gives you the whole body.  That's what it does and if you do `console.log(body)`, you will see what data it has.  If the body is JSON and you want it parsed so you can get access to the `data` property, then you will have to parse it to convert the string into JSON.  You can either do that manually or you can set an option on `request()` to have it parse the JSON for you.

Comment: okay thank you , , so if i covert the data to json so its posible to get the data only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the body of your request is JSON, then you have to parse it to turn it into a Javascript object so you can access the `.data` property.

You can do that by passing the `json: true` option to `request()` and it will parse the JSON for you.

Or, you can manually parse the body with `let result = JSON.parse(body)`.

---

Here's how you set the `json: true` option:

```
router.get('/',  (req, res,next) => {

    request({
       url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/promos',
       json: true
    },  (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) { 
            res.send('An erorr occured')
            console.log(error)
        }
        else {
            res.send(body.data)
        }
    });
});
```